# How do I remove extra zeros that appear after parsing date and time columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am reading an excel file into a dataframe which contains date and time in separate columns. I tried parsing the date and time when reading them in, however, there seems to be extra zeros in between the parsed date and time column. What would be the best solution to get rid of these zeros.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('/home/alton/Documents/Solar_Data/Raw_Radiation_ Data_2011_to_ 2016.xlsx', sheet_name= '2011', parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
```

I expect the following:

```
                 Date_Time  Min.  Max.  Average W/m2
6324  31/12/2017 19:59:59   0.0   0.0           0.0
6325  31/12/2017 20:59:59   0.0   0.0           0.0
6326  31/12/2017 21:59:59   0.0   0.0           0.0
6327  31/12/2017 22:59:59   0.0   0.0           0.0
6328  31/12/2017 23:59:59   0.0   0.0           0.0
```

but I am getting

```
                        Date_Time    Min.    Max.  Average W/m2
4870  2016-12-02 00:00:00 12:59:59  203.3  1065.7         848.2
4871  2016-12-02 00:00:00 13:59:59  211.1  1011.4         751.1
4872  2016-12-02 00:00:00 14:59:59   91.5   867.2         429.8
4873  2016-12-02 00:00:00 15:59:59  138.3   562.8         346.2
4874  2016-12-02 00:00:00 16:59:59   38.3   286.3         159.4
```

Comment: Can you try also specifying date_parser and dayfirst ? See notes at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html
Also, can you provide how the date/time is formatted in your XLSX?

Comment: Are 'Date' and 'Time' two separate columns in your spreadsheet?

Comment: @ScottBoston yes they are